# How to draw self-call in sequence diagram

Tags: app.diagrams.net

The built-in self-call in the UML shapes library is misplaced.

Attached shows the desired one and the current one. Making the desired one I have to make several clicks, draw, tweaks on the line. Any more convenient steps to create it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added it here https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/1829 so you could track the progress.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

As Marija [said](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/151050/how-to-draw-self-call-in-sequence-diagram/151077#151077), it's not possible.

But perhaps, this workaround will save you work in the future.

1. Take the original "self call"
2. Do your several clicks, draws and tweaks on the line
3. Group it
4. Drag-and-drop your updated "self call" as template to the Scratchpad
   [image]
5. Then, in the future, you can just reuse the "self call" from the Scratchpad instead of the other one from the UML section